# Add variable to multiple data frames that equals part of the data frame name

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 70 .csv dataset files that have data from the Mullen Scales of Early Learning (MSEL). The MSEL is made up of a composite scores and scores from 4 different subscales. Let's call these "subsc". These data also come from different developmental periods. The combination of these all make up my different datasets, which are named using the following nomenclature: "msel"+"[subsc]"+"_"+"[period]" (e.g., mselcomp_t1, mselcomp_yr2, mselvl_t1, etc). Each of these datasets has exactly the same variables.

What I am ultimately trying to do is combine all these datasets, but I need a way to identify which rows came from which dataset (i.e., which time period and which subscale). So, I want to read each .csv file in, add a column called "subsc" that contains the portion of the data frame before "_ [period]", and another column called "period" that takes on the portion of the data frame after "msel[subsc]_". I hope that makes sense.

Basically, what I want to know is, is there an easy way to streamline the following code using a for loop (I will do this for 3 datasets so you can get the idea, but I will need to do this 70 times)?:

```
mselcomp_t1 <- read_csv("mselcomp_t1.csv")
  mselcomp_t1$subsc <- "mselcomp"
  mselcomp_t1$period <- "t1"

mselcomp_yr2 <- read_csv("mselrl_yr2.csv")
  mselrl_yr2$subsc <- "mselrl"
  mselrl_yr2$period <- "yr2"

mselfm_yr2 <- read_csv("mselfm_yr2.csv")
  mselfm_yr2$subsc <- "mselfm"
  mselfm_yr2$period <- "yr2"

msel_all <- rbind(mselcomp_t1, mselrl_yr2, mselfm_yr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider running `lapply` on list or vector of the CSVs to parse files iteratively and assign needed columns into a list. Then, at the end `rbind` on the list of data frames with `do.call`.

```r
mse_dfs <- lapply(
  c("mselcomp_t1.csv", "mselrl_yr2.csv", "mselfm_yr2.csv"),
  \(f) transform(
     read.csv(f),
     subsc = strsplit(f, "_")[[1]][1],
     period = sub("\\.csv", "", strsplit(f, "_")[[1]][2])
  )
)

mse_all <- do.call(rbind, mse_dfs)
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to append this to read the data in, too?

Comment: Also, is there supposed to be a slash in front of the (f) transform? I'm getting an error at that slash - specifically, ,"Error: unexpected input"

Comment: Whoops! Simply wrap `f` with `read.csv` inside the `transform` call (handy method to quickly add/adjust columns to a data frame). See [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76600749/revisions). And yes, that is a backslash and not a typo. With R version 4.1.0+ the anonymous lambda can be written out as `function` or backslash.

Comment: That's still not working. Here is the error I'm getting```> msel_dfs <- lapply(
+   c("mselcomp_t1.csv", "mselrl_yr2.csv", "mselfm_yr2.csv"),
+   \(f) transform(
Error: unexpected input in:
"  c("mselcomp_t1.csv", "mselrl_yr2.csv", "mselfm_yr2.csv"),
  \"```

Comment: Since you appear to have an older R version, replace backslash with the word `function`. Both are equivalent in v4.1.0+.